# Why swagger documentation doesn't work on PythonAnywhere domain?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, pythonanywhere

I have used swagger to document my APIs on the Django rest framework, and deploy it on Pythonanywhere.
but the documentation URL doesn't have any response.
[image]

it is my urls.py code for swagger:

```
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view
from drf_yasg import openapi
     schema_view = get_schema_view(
       openapi.Info(
          title="BoardGame API",
          default_version='v1',
          description="Test description",
          terms_of_service="http://****.pythonanywhere.com/",
          contact=openapi.Contact(email="contact@boardgame.local"),
          license=openapi.License(name="TEST License"),
       ),
       public=True,
       permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),
    )
    urlpatterns = [
        ...
        path('', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
    ]
```

and my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'drf_yasg',
    'rest_framework_swagger',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'django_extensions',
   ...
]
```

Comment: It does have a response. It's showing you some sort of Django page. That suggests that your swagger docs may just not be on the root URL. Check your other urls.py files to determine which path your swagger docs are publixhed on.

Answer (score 2):

Its because your static files has not been loaded on server try to collectstatic files and check in inspect of page whether css is loading or not

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to learn about static in Django
2. When you apply it all UI related files will be created in a static folder
3. Then swagger UI will work on pythonanywhere

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that static file is not loaded on live server:
step 1:

```
LOCAL= False
```

step 2:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

step 3:
Reset server

```
nginx: sudo systemctl restart nginx
gunicorn: sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

1. run the collectstatic command
2. Go to the webapps page
3. provide static file location in the **Static files:** section in the page